# Best way to change an attribute in a list of objects? (python)

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I want to edit multiple instances of an object as efficiently as possible. Right now my code looks like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, att):
        self.att = att

num_instance = 100
list_instance = [MyClass(some_value[i]) for i in range(num_instance)]
```

I want to somehow edit the attributes in all the instances in the list without using an explicit for loop; which is what I am doing right now:

```
for i in range(num_instance):
    list_instance[i].att = some_other_value[i]
```

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe using a different data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use list comprehension. Replace this:

```
for i in range(num_instance):
    list_instance[i].att = some_other_value[i]
```

with this:

```
[list_instance[i].set_att(some_other_value[i]) for i in range(num_instance)]
```

and add the set_att function to the class:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, att):
        self.att = att

    def set_att(self, att):
        self.att = att
```

Alternatively, you could just call `init` with an input instead of writing a `set_att` function that just does the same thing.

List comprehension is slightly faster than the traditional `for` loop.